# node js with sequelize. Not able to insert in table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

1. Background
2. Using nodejs version 12.
3. The table "user" is created in MySQL database dapdb.
4. When I try to write a record to the table - authController - Postman depicts:
   "{
   "status": "Success ",
   "data": {}
   }"
5. No data is written to the table, which is the problem. Files are below.

server.js

```
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });
    const db = require('./database/db');
    const app = require('./app');
    ///////////////////////////////
    // 4. Start Server
    const port = process.env.PORT || 90;
    
    db.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
      app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`App running on port ${port}...`);
      });
    });
```

---

```
   // db.js
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const db = {};
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.db, process.env.logonid, process.env.password, {
      host: process.env.host,
      port: process.env.dbport,
      dialect: 'mysql',
    });
    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
    module.exports = db;
```

---

```
    //userModel.js
   const db = require('./../database/db');
    Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const validate = require('validator');
    
    const User = db.sequelize.define('user', {
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        trim: true,
        required: [true, 'Please give me your name!'],
        len: [3 - 50],
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
        trim: true,
        required: true,
        lowercase: true,
        validate: [validate.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email.'],
        photo: Sequelize.STRING,
        password: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          required: [true, 'Please provide a password.'],
          minlength: 8,
        },
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      passwordConfirm: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        required: [true, 'Please provide a password confirmation.'],
      },
    });
    module.exports = User;
```

---

```
    // authController.js
    const db = require('./../database/db');
    const User = require('./../models/userModel');
    exports.signup = async function (req, res, next) {
      const newUser = await db.sequelize.sync().then(function () {
        User.create({
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: req.body.password,
          passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm,
        });
        console.log(req.body);
      });
      res.status(201).json({
        status: `Success `,
        data: {
          user: newUser,
        },
      });
    };
```

---

```
      // app.js
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const userRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const app = express();
```

---

```
///////////////////////////////
// 1. Middlewares

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // console.log('Hello from the middleware');
  next();
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.requestTime = new Date().toISOString();
  next();
});
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRouter);
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your result is not returning anything. You can try this:

```js
 const db = require('./../database/db');
    const User = require('./../models/userModel');
    exports.signup = async function (req, res, next) {
      const newUser = await User.create({
          name: req.body.name,
          email: req.body.email,
          password: req.body.password,
          passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm,
        });
        console.log(req.body);
      res.status(201).json({
        status: `Success `,
        data: {
          user: newUser,
        },
      });
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, Piyush for your response.  When I run your snippet in Postman it just spins and I have to cancel.  In the console I get "POST /api/v1/users/signup - - ms - -"

Comment: // app.use(bodyParser.json());
// Changed code to this
// Auto-fill fields (id, updatedAt, and createdAt) were written to database, but none of the req.body fields
exports.signup = async function (req, res, next) {
  const newUser = await User.create(req, {
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password,
    passwordConfirm: req.body.passwordConfirm,
  });
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(201).json({
    status: `Success `,
    data: {
      user: newUser,
    },
  });
};

Comment: // Postman output:
{
    "status": "Success ",
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "id": 9,
            "updatedAt": "2020-08-07T14:42:59.009Z",
            "createdAt": "2020-08-07T14:42:59.009Z"
        }
    }
}

Comment: user5889334, a very late thank you for your response.  I was a real newbie when I posed that question.  :-)